# JSON Columns in API Laravel Add not insert

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, model-view-controller

when I go to do the "add" via POST the json is not inserted. I would like to insert in the "paramJson" column a json via api / polls. but it gives me problems

I have the following fields:

```
public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('polls', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->text('now');
                $table->json('paramJson');
                $table->enum('status', ['a', 'b', 'c','d'])->default('a');
            });
        }
```

Poll model:

```
protected $fillable=[
        'now',
    ];

protected $casts = [
        'paramJson' => 'array',
    ];
```

PollsController.php

```
public function add(Request $request)
    {
        $poll = Poll::create($request->all());
        return response()->json($poll, 201);
    }
```

Route API

```
Route::post('polls','PollsController@add');
```

I make the post call http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/polls. where I send a json as follows:

```
{
 "now": "did the MJ12 exist?",
 "paramJson" : "{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}"
}
```

gives the following error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364

while if I insert it so it takes it:

```
{
 "now": "did the MJ12 exist?",
 "paramJson" : "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}"
}
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'paramJson'

while if I insert it from DB I see it like this

```
INSERT INTO polls (now, paramJson) values ("did the MJ12 exist?", '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}') 

"paramJson":"{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}",
```

it is not possible to insert a json in laravel like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your JSON is encoded incorrectly. Try:

```
{
 "now": "did the MJ12 exist?",
 "paramJson" : {
     "key1": "value1", 
     "key2": "value2"
 }
}
```

ie leave double quotes off the value of paramJson. `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` not `"{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}"`

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'paramJson' doesn't have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

i change

Poll model:

```
protected $fillable=[
                'now',
           'paramJson',
            ];
protected $casts = [
                'paramJson' => 'array',
            ];
```

it works